# Storing Array of Integers in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in which  I want to store a list of Days chosen (Sun-Sat) But to keep it simple i want to store as ints 1 to 7.

Doing some research I've found 2 ways to handle this "correctly".

creating boolean columns for each day... "Monday" = "False" if not chosen etc.

I really don't like this... too many columns

Another method is to have a table that only holds a composite key

For example day_event

```
dayID eventID
```

So if the

event 1 had day 1 2 3

and event 2 had day 2 5 it would be something like this

```
day : event
1 : 1
2 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 1
5 : 2
```

then i would be able to select * from day_event where eventID = 2 and so on to get my list of days....
But i really don't like this either... all that just to store a few days?

To me it seems more simple, and practical to have a string column like 'days' like "1,2,3" and "2,5" respectively, as wrong
as it may be.

Is there another solution?

Comment: when dealing with sql, stop thinking in "array" terms. SQL is a set-based environment. But no, there's no other solution. you either go with a 7-column table, one col for each day, or a single col for "days" and dayIDs in the columns. While it's unlikely we'll ever end up with 8-week days (Hungoverday? Atworktoolongday?), generally speaking closely related data should go into its own sub-table, e.g.: normalize the design.

Comment: @MarcB the "Stop thinking in terms of arrays" is something I support. But the other part, well check my answer. Sets are limited to 64 bits so if you're not storing 7 days but a list of more than 64 things then obviously you'll need a separate table.

Comment: @MihaiStancu yes it does make sense to have a new table with such a large set of items, but for simple situations like this its like a code smell to normalize. SET will work nicely thanks.

Comment: Taking normalization to the (absolute) max leads to EAV structures. There is no (little) structural redundancy EAV but it's also tremendously wasteful in terms of performance, ease of use, ease of reading, etc..

Comment: Many high-load applications require de-normalizations to ensure computational ease of access to data (even if it may be stale at some point).

Comment: So normalization is not a goal or an absolute truth. It's just another one of the useful tools you need to balance well to get what you want/need out of it.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: I'm talking about sets in general, not the set TYPE in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it as a [`SET` column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) defined as:
    CREATE TABLE `table_name` (

```
    /* ... */

    `column_name`SET(
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday',
        'Sunday'
    ),

    /* ... */
);
```

A set is like a bitmask so (for example) both Monday and Wednesday could be active simultaneously in the column value.

Sets are limited to a total of 64bits (meaning 64 values) -- which in your case is not a problem.

In your case the SET type is very adequate because you can even filter by this column with very little overhead (compared to the other options the string ad the table this is 0 almost overhead).

```
SELECT *
    FROM `table_name`
    WHERE `column_name` = 'Monday,Wednesday'
```